# Сброс Id таблицы на ноль из программы

Tags: c#, sql

Как можно из программы (т.е. не на сервере) сбросить Id на ноль при удалении всех записей из таблицы??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Счетчик сбрасывается, если удалять все записи оператором

[TRUNCATE TABLE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_delete_statement/page2.html)

Answer (score 5):

Выполнить [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

```sql
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Table1', RESEED)
```

из C# это можно выполнить как обычный запрос, используя классы `SqlCommand`/`SqlConnection`:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Table1', RESEED)", connection);
    connection.Open();
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: примерчик можно, как из С# это можно сделать?

Comment: @VladimirTsybin это обычный SQL запрос. на клиенте его можно вызвать через SqlCommand, как какой-нибудь `SELECT`. Вам нужен полный пример?

Comment: @VladimirTsybin и в SQL Server нет понятия "на сервере". Сервер - это сервис, без интерфейса. SQL Management Studio - это просто клиент к нему, ей можно подключится к любому другому серверу, а не только к тому, который находится на той же машине.

Comment: @VladimirTsybin ловите пример (не проверял, но должен работать)

Comment: Спасибо, но этот пример не работает.

Comment: @VladimirTsybin только что проверил - работает. Ну ок, можете использовать пример из ответа с вариантом `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE <tableName> ALTER COLUMN <columnName> IDENTITY (<newSeed>, 1);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(SQL.80).aspx